# How to pass multiple parameters as individual multiple pages on an SSRS report?

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, ssrs-2008, reporting, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a report in SSRS that is mostly static, but has a tablix and a couple text boxes that correspond to a query that returns information for an order number.  Currently, that query is designed for ONE order number.

What I want is for the report to look as it does now, but with the ability to select multiple order numbers and generate the report for each one, but all at once.

My problem is that the report will try to combine all the fields for all the order nos onto one page.  I do not want that; I want each page to look the same, but with the different text boxes and expressions corresponding to the specific order number information.

Please let me know if you need more context or pictures.  Attached is a picture of the report. The red circle is where the order specific info will be, and the order number up top is also pulled in.

[image: report Example]

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do this:

Make a new report that is the same size as your existing report, but that has a multi-select parameter for OrderNumber.

Put a List item on the report, with the item size being the size of your existing report.

Put a DataSet on the report that returns one row per OrderNumber selected in the OrderNumber parameter.

Put a subreport in the List Item, and point the subreport to your existing report.

Wire the OrderNumber from the List's DataSet to pass through to the sub-report Order Number parameter.

And I think that should do it.   Going off the top of my head, so I may have missed some small thing.   Any SSRS sub-report tutorial should be able to guide you the rest of the way.

Comment: Any chance you could link to an example? I'm not quite 100% following you.

Comment: Don't have anything handy, but do you have a specific question about some step?

Comment: The third step... so when I put the DataSet in the new report, should I be writing a query? Just a little confused there

Comment: I think so.  I don't think a list can be tied to a parameter, I think it has to be a dataset.   There may be some way around this, but I've never needed one before.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "put a dataset ... that returns one row per OrderNumber"? One row of the same results that is in my previous report? Sorry, I just don't quite understand what the list needs to pass